# Confirming eclipse is running a correct version of Scala for Play

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

This should be easy. I've installed play 2.3.7 with the typesafe activator, and later followed https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE to set up the demo project of it for eclipse (eclipse Kepler). While the demo project runs as intended, things look a bit quirky inside eclipse, and I suspect my eclipse uses Scala 2.10 whereas Play jars are 2.11. 
How do I confirm and resolve this?

Oddly enough by the way, eclipse seems to keep showing and resolving errors in the Problems pane, e.g many errors like:

- akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.11). In case of errorneous report, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.
- play-functional_2.11-2.3.7.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.11). In case of errorneous report, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.

A nice explanation about how eclipse doesn't crash altogether trying to use 2.11 class files using a 2.10 compiler would also be much appreciated :)

Comment: Larger problem is, I use 2.10 for all my Scala projects, so being able to use latest Play with scala 2.10 may be more helpful right now, in case that's possible!

Comment: If you're using maven, try changing all the _2.11 artifactIds in the pom.xml to _2.10

Comment: Actually using sbt, forgot to say.